# Youtube play and quit options handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, macos

I am running the YouTube video on the UIWebView and the video plays fine. But it takes time to buffer the video and then display video.
So i require 2 delegates to handle the following events:
  -- When the YouTube actually starts playing the vedio.
  -- When the UIWebView is quit from the actual view.
Any help on these will be a great help for me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the delegate method of UIWebview control and it raise when video is about to start.

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The issue here is i tried with the delegate, however when the video starts playing the delegate doesn't get called.

Comment: Sorry that i forgot to connect the delegate. Now its getting called.